# TYPO3 v11, can not send emails - Unable to connect to localhost:25 (Connection timed out)

Tags: email, typo3, typo3-11.x

With TYPO3 v11, it's impossible to send emails. I have this error :

> Could not deliver mail
> Please verify $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL'][*] settings are valid. Error message: Connection could not be established with host "localhost:25": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to localhost:25 (Connection timed out)

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Everything worked fined with TYPO3 v9 but with the same config on the same server, the problems occurs.

Comment: If you provide your mail configuration from LocalConfiguration.php, maybe someone can help.

Comment: Your local SMTP isn't responding on port 25. If that's not your intended server, sounds like a configuration issue.

Comment: I put [MAIL][transport] = mail
which was automatically changed to 
[MAIL][transport] = sendmail
now it works.

Comment: Maybe this could've your problem: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Feature-88643-NewMailAPIBasedOnSymfonymailerAndSymfonymime.html

Comment: You should take a look for an alternative as `mail` is insecure.

Comment: It works with [MAIL][transport] = sendmail
A bit weird because I already tried that with an error but when I set [MAIL][transport] = mail and it changed it automatically to sendmail, it worked.